# Hive query to get the oldest string timestamp in a table

Tags: sql, hiveql, hue

Hi I want to find the oldest date from a string date column in format `20180209 00:00:00`.

I am using the following query to get the string  column in `date` format

```
select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(acc_last_change_date,  'yyyyMMddHHmmss')) from ACCOUNTS
```

but the result is returned as `null`.

Could you help  me on same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `min()`:

```
select min(acc_last_change_date)
from accounts;
```

Your string is in a suitable format for using `min()`.

If you want the entire row, you can use:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
order by a.acc_last_change_date
limit 1;
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but what function should I use to convert it into timestamp date format